# JHipster war not working in tomcat?

Tags: jhipster

my jhipster application does not work when I deploy my war file in a standard tomcat 8. It seems that some URL, especially for the REST services are absolute without the context of the application.For example my application has the base URL localhost:8080/myapp, I am able to login, but eg. the API administration menu does not work, because swagger wants to use the URL localhost:8080/#/docs and not localhost:8080/myapp/#/docs.
When I rename myapp.war to ROOT.war everything is working fine.
What is going wrong here ?

BTW.
I am using JHipster 2.20

Comment: Same Issue. Using the same workaround of renaming the war to ROOT.war :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit your URLs?

I am using tomcat 8 as well with x.x.x.x:8200/myapp/ naming as well, and the whole app is working fine, including swagger.

Your problem sounds more like an angular-ui-router problem.

Did you change anything in the main js file or in the navbar.html file?

It's important to keep the `<a ui-sref="docs">` link style.
You can also try to create a new base app in jhipster and deploy that to your tomcat server, see if the problem still happens.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to context path change. You have changed your context path to myapp while swagger is still looking for root path /.

You need to update your swagger index.html with new url

var url = "/myapp/v2/api-docs";